# Powershell AzureAD App Registration Permissions New-AzureADApplication -RequiredResourceAccess

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am having a problem with the following code. I am trying to assign the following permissions to an App Registration in AzureAD using the -RequiredResourceAccess  property from New-AzureADApplication. I keep getting an invalid value for $reqGraph?

Please help?

> New-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing NewApplication
> Code: Request_BadRequest Message: Invalid value specified for property
> 'resourceAppId' of resource 'RequiredResourceAccess'. RequestId:
> 5abf5ea5-8f94-4d14-8e8d-8f12a92bf3e5 DateTimeStamp: Mon, 17 May 2021
> 07:12:02 GMT Details: PropertyName  - resourceAppId, PropertyErrorCode
>
> - InvalidValue HttpStatusCode: BadRequest HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request HttpResponseStatus: Completed

```
$appName = "Test" # Maximum 32 characters
$adalUrlIdentifier = "https://abc.dk/AADGuestLifecycleMgmt"
$appReplyUrl = "https://www.abc.dk"
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a secure password for your certificate!'
$certStore = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
$currentDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $currentDate.AddYears(10) # 10 years is nice and long
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "abc.dk" -CertStoreLocation $certStore -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $endDate).Thumbprint
$thumb > cert-thumb.txt # Save to file
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "$certStore\$thumb" -FilePath .\AzureADGuestLifecycleMgmt.pfx -Password $pwd
$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("$path\AzureADGuestLifecycleMgmt.pfx", $pwd)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())

Install-Module AzureAD
Import-Module AzureAD
# Connect to Azure AD as an admin account
Connect-AzureAD 

# Store tenantid
$tenant = Get-AzureADTenantDetail
$tenant.ObjectId > tenantid.txt

# Add AuditLog.Read.All access
$svcPrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -match "Microsoft Graph" }
$appRole = $svcPrincipal.AppRoles | ? { $_.Value -eq "AuditLog.Read.All" }
$appPermission = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "$($appRole.Id)", "Role"

#Add Directory.ReadWrite.All access
$appRole2 = $svcPrincipal.AppRoles | ? { $_.Value -eq "Directory.ReadWrite.All" }
$appPermission2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "$($appRole2.Id)", "Role"

$reqGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$reqGraph.ResourceAppId = $svcPrincipal.AppId
$reqGraph.ResourceAccess = $appPermission, $appPermission2

Write-Host $reqGraph

# Create Azure Active Directory Application (ADAL App)
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "$appName" -IdentifierUris $adalUrlIdentifier -ReplyUrls $appReplyUrl -RequiredResourceAccess $reqGraph
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $application.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "$appName" -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $keyValue -StartDate $currentDate -EndDate $endDate.AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are more than one app registration whose name includes "Microsoft Graph" in your tenant. It causes you to get the wrong `$svcPrincipal.AppId` (in this case, it may be a combination of multiple app ids).

Please directly set `$reqGraph.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"`.

`00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is the app id of the Microsoft Graph app, which is a fixed value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
yes I found the issue... I was using $_.DisplayName -match "Microsoft Graph" instead of $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code with $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph"

```
appName = "Test" # Maximum 32 characters
$adalUrlIdentifier = "https://abc.dk/AADGuestLifecycleMgmt"
$appReplyUrl = "https://www.abc.dk"
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a secure password for your certificate!'
$certStore = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
$currentDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $currentDate.AddYears(10) # 10 years is nice and long
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "abc.dk" -CertStoreLocation $certStore -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $endDate).Thumbprint
$thumb > cert-thumb.txt # Save to file
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "$certStore\$thumb" -FilePath .\AzureADGuestLifecycleMgmt.pfx -Password $pwd
$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("$path\AzureADGuestLifecycleMgmt.pfx", $pwd)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())

Install-Module AzureAD
Import-Module AzureAD
# Connect to Azure AD as an admin account
Connect-AzureAD 

# Store tenantid
$tenant = Get-AzureADTenantDetail
$tenant.ObjectId > tenantid.txt

# Add AuditLog.Read.All access
$svcPrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }
$appRole = $svcPrincipal.AppRoles | ? { $_.Value -eq "AuditLog.Read.All" }
$appPermission = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "$($appRole.Id)", "Role"

#Add Directory.ReadWrite.All access
$appRole2 = $svcPrincipal.AppRoles | ? { $_.Value -eq "Directory.ReadWrite.All" }
$appPermission2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "$($appRole2.Id)", "Role"

$reqGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$reqGraph.ResourceAppId = $svcPrincipal.AppId
$reqGraph.ResourceAccess = $appPermission, $appPermission2

Write-Host $reqGraph

# Create Azure Active Directory Application (ADAL App)
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "$appName" -IdentifierUris $adalUrlIdentifier -ReplyUrls $appReplyUrl -RequiredResourceAccess $reqGraph
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $application.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "$appName" -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $keyValue -StartDate $currentDate -EndDate $endDate.AddDays(-1)
```